# Message on successful database entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a message upon a successful user registration however what I have doesn't seem to be working and just submits/refreshes the page. No message pops up even though data has successful been entered into the SQL database. Any tips or ideas?

```
<?php
    require('php/connect.php');
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
           echo $msg = "Successful Registration!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Learning PHP currently so sorry if there's a really obvious answer here!

Edit: Forgot to include echo. Just needed a second pair of eyes, sorry guys. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: you're not echoing anything. Use `echo $msg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all have this on consideration:

If you're getting started on PHP, please stop using mysql. It's deprecated, instead, you can use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

As for your issue, your message is not being printed. Please make sure you echo the `$msg` variable:

```
 $msg = "Successful Registration!";
 echo $msg;
```

In mysqli a standard connection would be:

```
$DBConnect = new mysqli('serverName', 'userName', 'userPassword', 'dbName');
```

And that's it, that's all you need to start querying your database using `mysqli`.

For a mysql connection, try debugging it, see if there's a connection:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userName', 'userPassword');
if (!$connection) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: PDO. My school is (stupidly) teaching this though at the moment.

Comment: Maybe just for the basics, and if they stay with this, I guess you have no choice, just make sure if you'll be a PHP programmer, not to use mysql. mysqli (which I use and strongly encourage you to) has an OO interface that is very easy to use. I'll show you how to create a connection, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo message

```
if($result)
{
    echo $msg = "Successful Registration!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "Successfully registered!";
?>
```